# How do I perform calculations on a string in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Country     Sales    Assets   
China       4B        320B
China       3B        125B
India       112M      100B
USA         39M       200B...
```

The **Sales** and **assests** columns have some values in billions and some in millions. Billions are denoted by **B** and millions as **M**. Now I want to check the total sales of a country but I can't do so as the values are **object** type. So I stripped the **B** from the columns and tried converting them to **float** values. But the values like **39M** cause a problem.

Since **1 billion**=**1000 million**, I want to convert the values in millions to that in billions. Like the values like **39M** should be converted to **0.039B**. So later I can strip off all the **B's** and convert them to float.

How do I do that?

Comment: Why can't you simply replace `B` and `M` with the correct number of zeroes?

Comment: Why aren't you using *numeric types* for your *numeric data*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use if need output in `billion`s:

- [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) because process multiple columns with lambda function
- first remove last char by [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str) and convert to `int`
- multiple by [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mul.html) with [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html)d values of `dict`
- last convert to `float` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html)

---

```
cols = ['Sales','Assets']
d = {'M': 10**-3, 'B':1}
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str[:-1]
                                     .astype(int).mul(x.replace(d, regex=True))
                                     .astype(float))
print (df)
  Country  Sales  Assets
0   China  4.000   320.0
1   China  3.000   125.0
2   India  0.112   100.0
3     USA  0.039   200.0
```

If you want change values to numbers only change `dict` values:

```
d = {'M': 10**6, 'B':10**9}
#same solution
print (df)
  Country         Sales        Assets
0   China  4.000000e+09  3.200000e+11
1   China  3.000000e+09  1.250000e+11
2   India  1.120000e+08  1.000000e+11
3     USA  3.900000e+07  2.000000e+11
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
data=df['Sales']

for value in data:

     char=value[-1]

     if char=='M'

        toadd=float(value[:-1]/1000.0)

     elif char=='B': 
        toadd=float(value[:-1])

    totalsales=totalsales+toadd
```